# Angular 2 not work in deploy

Tags: angular, typescript, deployment, web-deployment

I am working with Angular 2, before I deploy my application, now I have made about 3 changes but they work perfectly in my localhost, they work both running only the frontend and obtaining the data from the server, as well as doing the command "npm run build" so get the files, but from one moment to another tells me that my component dashboard can not solve all the parameters when I upload my changes to the server, the truth is that the only change I made was to modify a table, but I do not explain how works perfectly in my local and when I do deploy stops working, any ideas?

I attach screenshot of my web browser

[Web browser terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RJL2.png)

Please, I don't understand why my web app not work of a moment to other

**EDIT**

I can't see my media files and this is my nginx file.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name 54.12.12.142;

location = /favicon.ico {
    alias /home/ubuntu/tracker-web/trackerServer/favicon.ico;
}
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

location /static/ {
    root /home/ubuntu/tracker-web/trackerServer;
}
location /media/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias /home/ubuntu/tracker-web/trackerServer/media/;
}
location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/tracker-web/trackerServer/trackerServer.sock;
}
}
```

Before this work fine! But I don't understand why in this moment no.

Comment: when you deployed the code, did the delete the existing compiled code in the server (i mean the previous deployed code)?

Comment: Thanks!, but I can't see my images, only js and css, nothing of media and I don't touch nginx files.

Comment: how so you deploy ? do you do a aot build ?

Comment: @RahulSingh I updating my question

Comment: @RahulSingh I only do ´npm run build´

Comment: @sm433403 you need to do a npm build --prod . Dont go with dev build

Comment: but I change that in my main.ts
`import { environment } from './environments/environment.prod';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}`